# Connecting HyperSQLDb from Oracle sqldeveloper or eclipse datasource explorer

Tags: hsqldb

I am using `HyperSQl` in server Mode. I created a database using a java program. How can I connect to the database I created using `Eclipse Data Source Explorer` or `Oracle SQLDeveloper`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that RDBMS created using HyperSQL can be accessed by running the HSQL SErver instance.
The embedded database can be connected without running the server instance